# Multiple Apple devices under one Apple ID - iMessage issues

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, apple-id

We have three iPhones and an iPad all assigned to one Apple ID. Anytime I try to iMessage my mum on her phone (from my iPhone), it appears on my brother's iPhone. Then, when he replies (thinking the iMessage was to him), I receive the iMessage which is addressed from my mum - despite it being sent from his phone. I've deleted the Apple ID from received iMessages to see if that would fix it, but it has failed to give the desired outcome.

How do I need to configure iMessage on the iPhones so that each person is their own "entity" and prevent "crossing wires"?

Comment: Basic question but are you texting phone numbers or email addresses? Is it at all possible for you to split Apple IDs out? iMessage and Facetime work best on separate Apple IDs. It also gets each of you 5GB of iCloud storage.

Answer (score 5):

iMessage isn't designed to work with just one Apple ID. Instead of having all the iPhones and iPad on one Apple ID, it will be necessary to set up additional Apple IDs for the different users.

When you setup an iOS device and put in your Apple ID, it provisions ALL such services to that Apple ID. Go into Settings on each device (under Messages and FaceTime) and remove the Apple ID. Replace the Apple ID with a new Apple ID unique to each user. Here is a [guide](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4436) on creating new iCloud accounts for this purpose.

Better yet, provision each account completely with its own Apple ID. If a person wants to download an already-purchased app or song from a different account, you can temporarily change accounts in iTunes or App Store.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can quite associate one Apple ID across all of your devices but tailor settings so that each device only receives iMessages at one address.

Here's how!

http://www.cultofmac.com/220986/mastering-imessage-on-your-iphone-manage-multiple-devices-ios-tips/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score -1):

It's really easy you go into your settings and assen each phone the right number and only that number in imessageing and that will fix the problem but all the apple device have to be changed or it will keep happening

Comment: This really is such a poor answer...   you should consider removing it to prevent further embarrassment to yourself.